# Connecting to the Internet with wininet

Tags: c, wininet, getlasterror

I've set up a temporary server on my laptop at 127.0.0.1:8000 using Python's SimpleHTTPServer. I've written a small C program that is attempting to connect to the server
and look at a file there, `d.txt`. However, my program doesn't properly connect. `HttpSendRequestA` throws `ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND (00002EE7)` but the problem is higher up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wininet.h>

int main(void) {

  HINTERNET* openHandle;
  openHandle = InternetOpenA("Windows+NT+5.1",0, NULL, NULL, 0);

  HINTERNET* connectHandle;
  connectHandle = InternetConnectA(openHandle,"127.0.0.1",8000,NULL,NULL,0,3,0);

  HINTERNET* httpHandle;
  char* arr[] = {"text//*", NULL};
  httpHandle = HttpOpenRequestA(connectHandle, "GET", "d.txt", "HTTP/1.1", 0,
               arr,0,0);

  int result2;
  result2 = HttpSendRequestA(httpHandle, 0,0,0,0);
  printf("%d",result2);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```