# MinGW: Modify internet proxy options

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, proxy, mingw, internet-options

I am trying to modify the proxy settings in C++ without using visual C++. I found this:

```
const wchar_t* proxyName = pnt.wc_str(); // pnt is a wxString declared earlier in the code.
INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST OptionList;
INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION Option[3];
unsigned long listSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);
Option[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
Option[1].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
Option[2].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
OptionList.dwSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);
OptionList.pszConnection = NULL;
OptionList.dwOptionCount = 3;
OptionList.dwOptionError = 0;

DWORD proxyType = PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT;

if (proxyName)
{
    if (proxyName[0])
    {
        proxyType = PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;
    }
}

Option[0].Value.pszValue = (LPWSTR)proxyName;
Option[1].Value.dwValue = proxyType;
if (on)
{
    Option[2].Value.pszValue = (LPWSTR)L"";
}
else
{
    Option[2].Value.pszValue = (LPWSTR)L"";
}
OptionList.pOptions = Option;

if (!InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &OptionList, listSize))
{
    // handle error
}

InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, NULL);
```

However because I have to use MinGW and MinGW's wininet.h is very different, I get "'INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST' was not declared in this scope" among other "not declared" messages. In all my searching I have not found anything on it, thanks to visual c++ being so prominent. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978216/connecting-to-the-internet-with-wininet) but it has almost no views, doesn't have *any* answers, and has not been touched almost a month and it's not even quite what I am looking for. I can't seem to find any documentation either. Any ideas? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I found this interesting repository: https://gitorious.org/w64/w64/source/8debddd9a43d7b8d841d3ebc1dd8a46782eac120:mingw-w64-headers/include/wininet.h#Lundefined - after including this header instead of MinGW' native one, program compiled almost fine - I just had to edit the header and comment out the union of "__MINGW_EXTENSION" - and just keep union's content as direct variables.... then It compiled completely fine :) Not tested if actually works, but compile-error-free start is a good start :)